# Are community AMI's eligible for EC2 free tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS [states](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-limits.html):

> When you start an Amazon EC2 instance, you must select an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) that is eligible for the AWS Free Tier. Because of licensing restrictions, some AMIs aren't eligible for the AWS Free Tier.

It's also [stated](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)

> To stay within the Free Tier, use only EC2 Micro instances.

Are some community AMIs eligible for the free tier if they are open source and can be run on a `t2.micro` instance?

**Edit:** It seems it might be the case that some are eligible, as a comment in the AWS [forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=96991) states:

> There are some community AMI's that are eligible for the free tier. You can see these by selecting the AMI, and then looking at the available Instance Types. If there is a "Micro" option annotated with a star then it is eligible.

Moreover an answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62979626/how-to-get-aws-ec2-ami-image-id-of-a-given-operating-system-using-java-sdk-descr) also explains this could be true.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed `ami-07f493412d6213de6` which is `NixOS 20.09.1632.a6a3a368dda x86_64-linux`, and also happens to be a community `ami`.

The result was that it was detected as free tier usage when verifying on the [billing](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/) page.

| Service | Free Tier usage limit | Month-to-date usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud | 750 hours per month of Amazon EC2 Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro or t3.micro instance dependent on region | 0.18% (1.32/750 Hrs) |
| Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud | 30 GB of Amazon Elastic Block Storage in any combination of General Purpose (SSD) or Magnetic | 0.02% (0.01/30 GB-Mo) |

It looks like `linux community ami's` can be considered free tier if they have no licence fee and are deployed on a free tier instance for less than `750 hours per month`.